# I want to display the third column in a DropDownList

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net

I have a `DropDownList` and everytime the user clicks on the list, I want to display the third value column (price).

```
value   name     price
1       carrot   5.00
2       apple    5.00
```

In the example above, when the user selects carrot, 5.00 should be displayed in a `TextBox`.

```
<html>
    <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlGruit" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" name="fruit"></asp:dropdownlist>
    <asp:textbox id="txtPrice" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Columns="35" name="price">
</html>    

<script type="text/javascript">

$("[name=fruit]").on("select2-close", function() { 
            var cor_d = $("[name=fruit]").select2().find(":selected").data("price")
            $("[name=price]").val(cor_d).trigger("change");


        });

</script>
```

The `DropDownList` data populates from database via VB.NET and I am trying to use JavaScript to avoid roundtrips to the database just to get the price value.

Comment: Using `data-` attributes is a decent choice, but you'll have to manually add the `data-` attribute to the ListItems in code-behind after you've databound the dropdownlist. You need to loop through them and add the attribute to each one separately.

Comment: I think you may also have a syntax issue with your `asp:textbox`. There doesn't seem to be a closing tag.